# Get MAX date per day and return all rows with those dates

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a table that has a datetime field. There are multiple rows with various,sometimes identical, dates.

I am trying to find a LINQ query that can return to me an IList of ALL entries over the last *n* days, but for each day of rows returned, I should only see the rows from the MAX time.

e.g. if I have rows in a day with times of 4/4/16 1:00:00 and 4/4/16 2:00:00, I would expect to retrieve all rows with the latter date.

Additional clarification:

The entity has an attribute, let's say Category.  I want the query to return ONE IList, that is populated with every entity sorted by max date PER DAY and PER CATEGORY.  e.g.

```
Item1 | Category1 | 10/10/2016 11:00:00
Item1 | Category1 | 10/10/2016 11:00:00
Item1 | Category1 | 10/10/2016 11:00:00
Item1 | Category2 | 10/10/2016 11:00:05
Item1 | Category1 | 10/10/2016 11:00:05
Item1 | Category1 | 10/10/2016 11:00:05
Item1 | Category2 | 10/11/2016 11:00:00
Item1 | Category1 | 10/11/2016 11:00:00
```

I would expect the result to look like a list of:

```
Item1 | Category2 | 10/10/2016 11:00:05
Item1 | Category1 | 10/10/2016 11:00:05
Item1 | Category1 | 10/10/2016 11:00:05
Item1 | Category2 | 10/11/2016 11:00:00
Item1 | Category1 | 10/11/2016 11:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var n = new DateTime(2016, 10, 10);
var res = from data in list
          where data.Date >= n
          group data by new { data.Date.Year, data.Date.Month, data.Date.Day }
          into dataGroup
          select dataGroup.OrderBy(eg => eg.Date).Last();
```

Here's a little example:

```
class Data 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<Data> {
        new Data() { Date = new DateTime(2016, 10, 9, 11, 0 , 0) },
        new Data() { Date = new DateTime(2016, 10, 10, 11, 0 , 0) },
        new Data() { Date = new DateTime(2016, 10, 10, 13, 0, 0) },
        new Data() { Date = new DateTime(2016, 11, 10) },
        new Data() { Date = new DateTime(2016, 11, 11, 10, 0, 0) },
        new Data() { Date = new DateTime(2016, 11, 11, 9, 0, 0) },
    };

    var n = new DateTime(2016, 10, 10);

    var res = from data in list
                where data.Date >= n
                group data by new { data.Date.Year, data.Date.Month, data.Date.Day }
                into dataGroup
                select dataGroup.OrderBy(eg => eg.Date).Last();

    foreach (Data r in res.ToList())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(r.Date);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:

10/10/2016 1:00:00 PM
11/10/2016 12:00:00 AM
11/11/2016 10:00:00 AM

Comment: Issue I see here is that I am only returning the latest per day.  I am expecting to have multiple rows per day returned. For example, I have 100 records, 50 with the date 10/10/2016 11:00:00 and 50 with the date 10/10/2016 11:00:05.  I need to get the 50 with the max date, and then expand upon this to get me ALL records per day, but only with the max date per day

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to find a LINQ query that can return to me an IList of **ALL** entries over the last n days, but for each day of rows returned, I should only see the rows from the MAX time.

Then you need to filter the last *n* days data, group by *date*, find the *max time* within each date, select all rows within the date with the max time, and finally flatten the result:

```
var endTime = DateTime.Today; // uncomment to include today .AddDays(1);
var startTime = endTime.AddDays(-n);
var result =
    from e in db.Table
    where e.DateTime >= startTime && e.DateTime < endTime
    group e by e.DateTime.Date into dateGroup
    let maxTime = (from e in dateGroup select e.DateTime).Max()
    from e in dateGroup
    where e.DateTime == maxTime
    select e;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming `n` is an `int` for representing the last *`n`* days.

```
            DateTime sinceLast = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-n);
            DateTime sinceLastAtMidnight = new DateTime(sinceLast.Year, sinceLast.Month, sinceLast.Day);

            var result =  lstDate.Where(x => x >= sinceLastAtMidnight)
                                 .Select(x => new
                                    { DateActual = x,
                                      DateWitoutTime = new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, x.Day) 
                                    }) 
                                 .GroupBy(x => x.DateWitoutTime)
                                 .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.DateActual).FirstOrDefault())
                                 .Select(x => x.DateActual)
                                 .ToList();
```